# I'm using NetBean GUI, and after I add or remove an item from the array and output it, it won't accept anymore input

Tags: arrays, user-interface, button, input, netbeans

I have to create a program that accepts input, puts them into two arrays (an original one and a sorted one). The add button adds the input into the array and the remove button is suppose to remove it. However, after I add or remove one string from the array, I can't do it again. It results in an error. Since I am new to Java, I don't know what kind of error it is, it just says this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
at CD_Collection.btnDisplayActionPerformed(CD_Collection.java:211)
at CD_Collection.access$000(CD_Collection.java:14)
at CD_Collection$1.actionPerformed(CD_Collection.java:65)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

This is my code:

```
    private void btnDisplayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    //display the updated collection
    //create a string of the array list (original)
    //reset the global strings
    fullStr = "";
    newList = "";
            
    for (String CD2 : CD) {
        fullStr = fullStr+" " + CD2 + "\n";
        intCount2 = intCount2 + 1;
    }
    
    //create another array to make a sorted list (a copy of the original list)
    ArrayList <String> CDNewSort = new ArrayList<>(CD); 
    Collections.sort(CDNewSort, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);//this sorts the list
    
    //turn the list into a string
    for (int i=0; i<intCount2; i++){
        newList = newList +" "+ CDNewSort.get(i)+"\n";
    }
    
    //print out new and updated arrays (unsorted and sorted list)
    this.txtOutput.setText("Original Order\n"+ fullStr +"\nSorted Order\n"+ newList);
    
    //disable/enable certain buttons to prevent repeats (in the array)
    btnDisplay.setEnabled(false);
    btnAdd.setEnabled(true);
    btnRemove.setEnabled(true);
    }                                          

    private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    //create a string variable and gather user's input
    String input = this.txtInput.getText();
    
    //add input to the array list
        CD.add(input);

    //enable/disable buttons to prevent duplicates
    btnDisplay.setEnabled(true);
    btnAdd.setEnabled(false);
    }                                      

    private void btnRemoveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    //gather the variable's value (user's input)
    String strRemove = this.txtInput.getText();
    
    //find the index of the item they want to remove
    index = Collections.binarySearch(CD, strRemove);
    
    //if the cd exists, it will remove it
    if (index > -1){
        CD.remove(index);//remove the item of the list that was inputed
    }
    
    //this tells the user that the cd they entered doesn't exist
    else {
        txtInput.setText("Sorry, that is not on the list.");
    }
    //enable/disable buttons to prevent duplicates
    btnRemove.setEnabled(false);
    btnDisplay.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of following lines:

```
btnDisplay.setEnabled(true);
btnAdd.setEnabled(false);
```

and

```
btnRemove.setEnabled(false);
btnDisplay.setEnabled(true);
```